# TestNg custom-emailable-report is not updating each time

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I have customised the emailable report using TESTNG framework.
But after running the test cases the custom-emailable-report.html file in test-output folder not get updated each time.
Anyone has answer for this ??Please help .